# Thunderbird: Keep focus on messages list

Tags: email, thunderbird

When I use the Keyboard to switch between the messages, some times I get this very bad behavior that every time I select a message element from the list, the focus moves from the messages list to the message content. So it becomes impossible to skim through my emails.

How can I keep the focus on the messages and move among them, and only switch to the message content window when I want (with a tab, mouse click, etc...)?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is only present  in TB 78.6.0 if the search box (CTRL F) in the reading pane is active. Otherwise the focus stays on the message pane.
I accidentally used CTRL F (I'm used to it from  Outlook) and thus ran into the issue. Closing the search bar on the bottom of the reading pane helped.

Comment: This bug is also [reported here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=424219).

Answer (score -1):

The problem has been reported and upgrading fixes it, see [this support forum answer](https://support.mozilla.org/questions/1127310#answer-888091).

Comment: The problem is again here: in 68.4.1 version. (